# How to Search by name using the Rest country Api

Tags: reactjs, typescript, search

When i search for a country, The searchInput useState works fine and receives the value, problem is it doesn't update the country in the Dom immediately unless i remove the useEffect hook dependency array, And this causes too many re-renders, So how can i update the DOM when i search search, Here is my code.

```
 const countryUrl = `https://restcountries.com/v2/name`;

 const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState<string>("Nigeria");
 const [countryData, setCountryData] = useState<object>([]);

 const fetchCountry = (searchInput: any) => {
    axios
      .get(`${countryUrl}/${searchInput}?fullText=true`)
      .then((res) => setCountryData(res.data[0]))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

 useEffect(() => {
    fetchCountry(searchInput);
  }, []);
```

```
 const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchWeather(searchInput);
    fetchCountry();
  };
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <input
                onChange={(e) => setSearchInput(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="Enter The Country"
                type="text"
              />
              <button type="submit">{<CiSearch />} </button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `searchInput` from `fetchCountry = (searchInput: any) => {`, it will look like `fetchCountry = () => {`

Reason is you have searchInput in useState so no need to pass as foo param

your fetchCountry will look like

```
 const fetchCountry = () => { // removed params
    axios
      .get(`${countryUrl}/${searchInput}?fullText=true`)
      .then((res) => setCountryData(res.data[0]))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

Comment: So i tried it exactly as you said and it still didn't work, I'm even getting `FetchCountry is not a function in my console.log`, In my App i am doing two Api calls, One for weather and one from the rest country Api to display the country information along with the weather, the way i did it works very well for the Weather Api but its not working for the rest country Api, hence my confusion